# What does Ynaxdh stand for? (Yeoman)

Tags: javascript, yeoman

I'm new to JavaScript automation stuff, especially yeoman (so new that I'm still delighted by the ASCII greet)

```
     _-----_
    |       |
    |--(o)--|   .--------------------------.
   `---------´  |    Welcome to Yeoman,    |
    ( _´U`_ )   |   ladies and gentlemen!  |
    /___A___\   '__________________________'
     |  ~  |
   __'.___.'__
 ´   `  |° ´ Y `
```

What does 'Ynaxdh' stand for? Yes, no, ... ?

Comment: the h is probably for help, and might give the explanation for the rest.

Comment: Which generator are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979390/what-does-ynaxdh-stand-for-yeoman/23153430#23153430

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Here the complete list of answers:

- Y: **y**es (Default)
- n: **n**o
- a: yes to this question and **a**ll others (or **a**lways yes).
- x: abort (e**x**it)
- d: show the **d**ifferences between the old and the new file
- h: **h**elp, list all options

So if you don't remember this definitions you can always enter h and see the list. Also in the new version, when you enter one of the letters you will see the definition showing behind the question.

The one in uppercase is the default one. If that is your choice, you can just hit enter.

Comment: If it helps, `a` is for "**a**lways yes" and `x` is for e**x**it.

Comment: wow, coming  back to this question 2 years later - thanks for filling in the missing details!

Answer (score 6):

`Ynaxdh` are the possible answers to the question you are being asked. For example:

```
[?] Overwrite Gruntfile.js? (Ynaxdh)
```

`Y` for yes

`n` for no

`h` likely stands for help, use it to find the rest of the definitions

Comment: this answer is incomplete; see the [more detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23153430/1341949) below

Answer (score 0):

While importing Jhipster-jdl.jh file you may also be faced with `(ynaxdH)`, which each letter stands as follow:

```
? Overwrite src\main\resources\config\liquibase\master.xml? (ynaxdH)
y) overwrite
n) do not overwrite
a) overwrite this and all others
x) abort
d) show the differences between the old and the new
h) Help, list all options
Answer:
```